# Storing GeoJSON FeatureCollection to PostgreSQL with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geojson, geometry

I am new to GeoJSON. I have a GeoJSON features collection as shown and would like to store it in postgres table (testtable). My postgres table has a serial id and geometry column.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    2565453.1826721914,
                    -3835048.659760314
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        2727584.7219710173,
                        -3713449.1942418693
                    ],
                    [
                        2732476.691781269,
                        -3992291.473426192
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            2442627.9025405287,
                            -3705499.954308534
                        ],
                        [
                            2425506.008204649,
                            -3886502.837287831
                        ],
                        [
                            2425506.008204649,
                            -3886502.837287831
                        ],
                        [
                            2555143.2081763083,
                            -3910962.686339088
                        ],
                        [
                            2442627.9025405287,
                            -3705499.954308534
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to insert the GeoJSON data into the table testtable.

How do I go about it?

I am using postgres version 9.3.5 with postgis version 2.1.3

---

I have been directed to previously asked questions which answer how to store a single feature eg a point or polygon. My question asks how to save multiple features in the GeoJSON file. By multiple features I mean a mixture of points, lines and polygon feature types in one file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a GeoJSON polygon into a PostGIS table?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60928/how-to-insert-a-geojson-polygon-into-a-postgis-table)

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have seen that question but it does not address my problem. I want to save a list of features, not just a single feature type. Please have a look at my GeoJSON features collection in my question.

Comment: @Jay So now either your question is "How do I break up a geojson collection into single features or you need to add more information (maybe storing information that those geometries belong to some sort of collection?)

Comment: Postgres as of version 9.2 has a JSON datatype, so you could just insert you JSON as is, if that is all you want to do. Version 9.4 has a much more useful JSONB datatype and indexing enhancements.

Comment: Or do you mean how do you split the GeoJSON into individual components and store those in Postgres, seeing as you haven't stated what the structure of testtable is.

Comment: Thank you @John for your response. Since I am new to GIS and  GeoJSON, I wanted some pointers with my problem at hand. Background of the question: A user draws the features on a map and I capture the collection of features drawn. I would like to save this collection in a DB with a unique id. Later, the saved data can be fetched for a supplied id. 
The testable in postgres has 2 columns. gid column that is a serial type, to hold the id, and geom column that is of geometry type.

Comment: Thank you @Jakub for your response. Those geometries belong to a collection, hence the "type": "FeatureCollection". Is it possible to store them without breaking the GeoJSON into individual components?

Comment: @Jay Yes, you can store the JSON but then it won't be a geometry so you won' be able to query for nearest neighbour easily etc. .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are [several JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) that can be used to extract the relevant parts of the [GeoJSON specification](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) required by [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) to create geometries.

Try the following, where you can replace the JSON in the top part:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT '{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
        },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
            ]
          },
        "properties": {
          "prop0": "value0",
          "prop1": 0.0
          }
        },
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
             [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
               [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
             ]
         },
         "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {"this": "that"}
           }
         }
       ]
     }'::json AS fc)

SELECT
  row_number() OVER () AS gid,
  ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry')) AS geom,
  feat->'properties' AS properties
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements(fc->'features') AS feat
  FROM data
) AS f;
```

Finds three geometries. The `geom` column has the geometry object, and the `gid` is the feature number. The `ST_AsText` function shows the [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) equivalent of each geometry. I've also included the `properties` or attributes that can be defined for each geometry, as is shown in the specification.

```
 gid |                   geom                   |              properties
-----+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
   1 | POINT(102 0.5)                           | {"prop0": "value0"}
   2 | LINESTRING(102 0,103 1,104 0,105 1)      | {                                   +
     |                                          |           "prop0": "value0",        +
     |                                          |           "prop1": 0.0              +
     |                                          |           }
   3 | POLYGON((100 0,101 0,101 1,100 1,100 0)) | {                                   +
     |                                          |            "prop0": "value0",       +
     |                                          |            "prop1": {"this": "that"}+
     |                                          |            }
(3 rows)
```

You should assign an SRID for the geometry, using ST_SetSRID.

Or if you simply need a single heterogeneous GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, you can make it compact like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry')))
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements('{ ... put JSON here ... }'::json->'features') AS feat
) AS f;

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(2565453.18267219 -3835048.65976031),LINESTRING(2727584.72197102 -3713449.19424187,2732476.69178127 -3992291.47342619),POLYGON((2442627.90254053 -3705499.95430853,2425506.00820465 -3886502.83728783,2555143.20817631 -3910962.68633909,2442627.90254053 -3705499.95430853)))
```

See also [Creating GeoJSON Feature Collections with JSON and PostGIS functions](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html) from the *Postgres OnLine Journal*, which does the opposite.