# Failure in importing geojson data in Postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I am new to both PostgreSQL and GeoJson. While following some of the tutorials online and some answer over here I wrote this line to import my geojson file:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=In user=postgres" "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\red\map.geojson" -nln locations -append
```

But this line produces a syntax error`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ogr2ogr"`

I also followed the instructions on this answer [Store GeoJson with Feature Collection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/store-a-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgres-with-postgis)

The data is shown but only on running the query given in the answer above. But how do I store this data. I am not able to find it by doing select * from table
_name.
Also the answer given on the above link shows data as expected but It is only shown the data and not storing it.

If anyone can help me insert the geojson file either by using the ogr2ogr or by helping me to insert data in table by using the link above.

Comment: Where did you type your command? It is a shell command, use cmd or powershell window. Donot forget to install gdal/ogr utilities.

Comment: i am running it in cmd. Also, Do I need to run it in postgresql env or jusr in cmd(if postgre is added to path variables)

Comment: if you installed PostgreSQL/PostGIS via EnterpriseDB or BigSQL distributions, GDAL should have come shipped with the installation. you should find the *ogr2ogr.exe* in *./path/to/postgres/PostgreSQL/<your_version>/bin* if I'm not mistaken (not 100% sure, you might need to search the installation path). see if you can execute your command in a cmd from within that folder containing the *.exe*. this folder needs to be added to *PATH* for windows to find it.