# Inserting GeoJSON in PostgreSQL using laravel controller

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

Actually.. I have GeoJSON that I send from javascript into controller. My GeoJSON:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [101.21719328770531, 3.113987284801912]
        },
        "properties": null
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [101.18330230120145, 3.046205311794175],
                [101.13585492009604, 2.985201536087212],
                [101.19008049850223, 2.9174195630794753]
            ]
        },
        "properties": null
    }]
}
```

and then I found this single heterogeneous `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` from this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis)

So, My SQL something like this:

```sql
SELECT public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_Collect(public.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry')), 4326) as geom
FROM (
      SELECT json_array_elements('{
                      "type":"FeatureCollection",
                      "features":[{
                                 "type":"Feature",
                                 "geometry":{
                                            "type":"Point",
                                            "coordinates":[101.21719328770531,3.113987284801912]
                                  },
                                 "properties":null
                      },{
                      "type":"Feature",
                             "geometry":{
                                        "type":"LineString",
                                        "coordinates":[[101.18330230120145,3.046205311794175],
                                                       [101.13585492009604,2.985201536087212],
                                                       [101.19008049850223,2.9174195630794753]
                                                      ]
                                        },
                             "properties":null
                      }]
                     }'::json->'features') AS feat
) AS f;
```

It can run it ... but, how can I insert this into my column geom in my table by using something like this `'geom' => db::raw("from my sql")`?

Comment: `INSERT INTO <your_table> (geom) (<your_query_above>);`? Or `UPDATE <your_table> SET geom = <your_query_above_without_select> WHERE <you_want_it>;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I already got answer..hahah.. first I send type string only to check type of GeoJson either Point, LineString, or Polygon.. the code something like this:

```
 $GeoJsonToData = json_decode($req->feature, true);
    $typeFeature = $GeoJsonToData["type"];
```

after that, Using condition if else to post that geometry into Table postgres db (Point/LineString/Polygon).. My code:

```
if($typeFeature == 'Point'){

          $savePointData = array(
            'name' => $req->name,
            'details' => $req->details,
            'geom' => \DB::raw("public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('$req->feature'), 4326)")
          );
          $allDataRekod = DrawPoint::create($savePointData);
          return "DrawSaving";
      }

      else if($typeFeature == 'LineString'){

          $saveLineStringData = array(
            'name' => $req->name,
            'details' => $req->details,
            'geom' => \DB::raw("public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('$req->feature'), 4326)")
          );
          $allDataRekod = DrawLineString::create($saveLineStringData);
          return "DrawSaving";
      }

      else if($typeFeature == 'Polygon'){

          $savePolygonData = array(
            'name' => $req->name,
            'details' => $req->details,
            'geom' => \DB::raw("public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('$req->feature'), 4326)")
          );
          $allDataRekod = DrawPolygon::create($savePolygonData);
          return "DrawSaving";
      }
```

And..Success!