# Efficiently convert a GeoJSON field to a single multipoint geometry in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have such PostGIS (PG:14-3.2) query today-:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id as "plant_id",
    p."location",
    p."name" as "plant_name",
    m."attributes_json",
    -- #placeholder,
    m."attributes_status",
    m."attributes_timestamp"
FROM metadata m
LEFT JOIN plant p
ON p.id = m.fk_plant_id
ORDER BY m.fk_plant_id ASC
;
```

The `attributes_json` is a GeoJSON feature containing multiple points.

I wish I could replace the `#placeholder` with a postgis MultiPoint as WKB or WKT which contains all the points of the GeoJSON field.

After some research, I end up there: [Storing GeoJSON FeatureCollection to PostgreSQL with PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis/142479#142479) and when adapting the given example to my situation, I succeed retrieving a single MultiPoint WKT object, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry')))
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(attribute_json::jsonb->'features') AS feat FROM metadata
) AS f;
```

But I'm not successful when it comes to inserting it at the place of the `#placeholder` in my initial query.

And if I replace the `#placeholder` by a one-shot statement:

```sql
    ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON((SELECT jsonb_array_elements(attributes_json::jsonb->'features'))->>'geometry')) as geom,
```

I have to add a `GROUPY BY` clause on almost every fields... and when it comes to adding the `m.attributes_json` in this clause, it says:

```
ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 18:  GROUP BY i.id, m.attributes_array, m.attribute_json
                                             ^
```

Any hints on how to achieve that in a proper and efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use

- a [correlated sub-query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

  ```
  SELECT
      p.id as "plant_id",
      p."location",
      p."name" as "plant_name",
      m."attributes_json",
      (
        SELECT
            ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(f -> 'geometry'))
        FROM
            JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(m."attributes_json"::JSONB -> 'features') AS f
      ) AS geom,
      m."attributes_status",
      m."attributes_timestamp"
  FROM
      metadata m
  LEFT JOIN
      plant p ON p.id = m.fk_plant_id
  ORDER BY
      m.fk_plant_id ASC
  ;
  ```
- a `[LEFT JOIN | CROSS JOIN] LATERAL [ON TRUE]`:

  ```
  SELECT
      p.id as "plant_id",
      p."location",
      p."name" as "plant_name",
      m."attributes_json",
      _m.geom,
      m."attributes_status",
      m."attributes_timestamp"
  FROM
      metadata m
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(f -> 'geometry')) AS geom
    FROM
        JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(m."attributes_json"::JSONB -> 'features') AS f
  ) AS _m
  LEFT JOIN
      plant p ON p.id = m.fk_plant_id
  ORDER BY
      m.fk_plant_id ASC
  ;
  ```

  *Note that with the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` syntax rows are omitted when the `LATERAL` query returns no results (much like `INNER JOIN` behavior). To get a `LEFT JOIN` behavior, use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( ... ) AS _m ON TRUE`. However, this is mainly an issue for set-returning functions.*

The `LATERAL` approach is more versatile (can return sets of rows), more elegant in set-returning scenarios, and, usually, much faster.