# Getting uploaded shapefile into geometry field on PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, geojson

I am working with a PHP web application where we have a user submitting a ShapeFile.

I am able to convert that ShapeFile then to a format of geojson.

What I am wondering now is how I can best get that geojson into a PostGIS table as a geometry column?

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to use `shp2pgsl` to directly load the shapefile into a PostGIS table, for example:

```
shp2pgsql -d -I shapefile.shp table | psql -U user database
```

If you prefer to use GeoJSON directly, there is `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`, but for this (as I understand), you'll need to parse and insert individual features from the GeoJSON file. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60945/9847) for additional details.

You can always keep the GeoJSON file on the server for transfer to the client, or export individual features from PostGIS as GeoJSON, using `ST_AsGeoJSON`

If going directly from shape to PostGIS doesn't fit your use case, perhaps include some additional information.