# PostGIS - OpenLayers - ST_GeomFromGeoJSON() Inserting wrong coordinates into database

Tags: postgis, openlayers, geojson

I have a project where I have Polygons drawn in a Openlayers map. These objects get turned into GeojSON using `format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry())`. This is my first project using a PostGIS database in combination with OpenLayers and GeoJSON.

Then I send them to a NodeJS backend who then sends this data to a PostGIS database. `'INSERT INTO plots (user_id, geog) VALUES ($1, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($2))'`. Where the `geog` is the Geojson that I receive from the frontend.

The problem that I am facing is that the coordinates get distorted inside the Database. This is an example of how the coordinates are represented inside the database:

[image]

Here is the Geojson from the above example that is being inserted into the Database:

```
{
   "type":"Polygon",
   "coordinates":[
      [
         [
            352847.7681741,
            6591493.68325289
         ],
         [
            352853.14118403,
            6591495.88702873
         ],
         [
            352865.86122686,
            6591501.10405905
         ],
         [
            352866.13573636,
            6591501.21660883
         ],
         [
            352866.14658836,
            6591501.22104384
         ],
         [
            352856.32964058,
            6591526.19583173
         ],
         [
            352854.06390643,
            6591531.95998212
         ],
         [
            352853.92222987,
            6591531.90191122
         ],
         [
            352766.24950317,
            6591495.94284857
         ],
         [
            352766.18921573,
            6591495.91814133
         ],
         [
            352778.56476466,
            6591465.29940885
         ],
         [
            352847.7681741,
            6591493.68325289
         ]
      ]
   ]
}
```

And the polygon that is being generated in the PostGIS database:

SRID=4326;POLYGON((47.76817410002695 -73.68325288966298,53.14118402998429 -75.88702872954309,65.86122686002636 -81.10405904985964,66.13573635998182 -81.21660882979631,66.14658836001763 -81.2210438400507,56.32964057999197 -73.80416826996952,54.06390642997576 -68.04001787956804,53.92222986998968 -68.09808878041804,-33.75049682997633 -75.94284856971353,-33.81078426999738 -75.91814132966101,-21.43523533997359 -45.29940885026008,47.76817410002695 -73.68325288966298))

Comment: seems to be a SRID issue. whats the SRID in the frontend?

Comment: @ziggy The SRID I use in the frontend is EPSG:3857.

Comment: Use `format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry(), {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', 'featureProjection': 'EPSG:3857'})` or `format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry(), {dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857', 'featureProjection': 'EPSG:4326'})` Never able to sort out between input and output depending if write or read...

Comment: To go from those projected coordinates (front end) to the geographic coordinates (database result), you have to be projecting it *somewhere* ..but that step isn't described in your question.

Comment: @ThomasG77 `format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry(), {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
  });` Was the fix! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60945/4968) to a related question, what happens if you add a node to your GeoJSON specifying the coordinate system, like this: `"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3857"}}` ?

Comment: @elrobis Where should I project them? They get projected in the frontend on a web application, then they are send to a nodejs where they are stored inside the postgis db.

Comment: @ThomasG77 For `.writeGeometry` method input CRS is `featureProjection` and output CRS is `dataProjection`, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html#writeGeometry

Comment: It looks like you've found a working solution in @ThomasG77's suggestion, as a matter of curiosity—if you're feeling experimental—I'd be interested to know if going back to your original approach and adding the coordinate system node to your GeoJSON also works. My expectations is that these would be two different solutions to the problem, where the lesson is that you needed to sync your coordinate systems somewhere before the geoms get pushed into the DB.

Comment: @elrobis How do I add the node to my GeoJSON. The GeoJSON is being generated by the formatter. Should I insert the coordinate system node manually to string that is being generated?

Comment: Edited my answer. Two ways to do it

Comment: If you've got the GeoJson in a variable already (for example `geoJsonFeature`), then it might work to add the CRS node using Array Notation, like this: `geoJsonFeature['crs']={"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3857"}};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made my comment an answer

**Solution 1**: reproject coordinates to client side and ingest them as is in server side

You need to reproject your coordinates from your frontend to backend. Your backend expects `EPSG:4326`. Your frontend use `EPSG:3857`. You need to transform the coordinates to `EPSG:4326` before sending them

So

```
format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry())
```

should become

```
format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry(), {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

**Solution 2**: Send coordinates as they are and transform them on server side

You could also do the opposite e.g keep `EPSG:3857` in your frontend. Send the geometry to the server

```
format.writeGeometry(plot.geometry.getGeometry())
```

and change before inserting your database the coordinates by reprojecting on PostGIS side

So, the following

```
INSERT INTO plots (user_id, geog) VALUES ($1, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($2));
```

would become

```
INSERT INTO plots (user_id, geog) VALUES ($1, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($2), 3857, 4326);
```